# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in angularjs and asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:7514/Employees/testrestricted 401 (Unauthorized) angular.js:10419
OPTIONS http://localhost:7514/Employees/testrestricted Origin http://localhost:4064 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. angular.js:10419
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:7514/Employees/testrestricted. Origin http://localhost:4064 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I have my app.js setup like this already:

```
var app = angular.module('angular-auth-demo', ['http-auth-interceptor']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', { templateUrl: 'partial-content.html', controller: 'ContentController' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);
```

is there a way to find out if this is an error on angular or asp.net mvc, because I have a cors configuration on that end too, but i don't think the browser is actually getting a chance to hit the server?

Comment: Did you found a solution for this? I still cant find way to fix this on post request.

Comment: @Pnct what seems to be the problem? Combining the two answers fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Working post request on cross domain? Only GET works on cross domain, dunno why POST is denying :/
OPTIONS api.domain Contact Origin app.domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. angular.min.js:106
XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.domain/Contact. Origin app.domain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: @Pnct what kind of backend are you running? IIS and MVC I'm assuming? Did you try adding the settings in the second post to your web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is getting to the server because the server is returning a 401. See the network tab in Chrome dev tools or Firebug. Assuming you have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header already, you probably need to specify the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header and add `Content-Type` as its value. Maybe post your CORS config/code?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue using Font Awesome cross domain - specifically with Firefox.

Adding a web.config in the directly with the resource you need to access with this solved it for me.

```
 <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

following solution worked for be:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1885459.aspx

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Context.Request.Path.Contains("signalr/negotiate"))
            {
                this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            }
        }
```